# Verify OSGi bundles dependencies (import-package) programmatically

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I need to validate whether the imported packages of a bundle are fulfilled by a set of other bundles' export packages. This should not be very hard to implement but I know all the OSGi containers plus eclipse (when you do "validate bundles" in PDE) do this. I just don't know how to find that code. Does anyone know what classes/libraries I could use that already implement all this logic?

My goal is to give a list of files (bundles) in the file system and do an analysis whether the set of bundles is self-contained and if not to show all the missing external imports/requires. all this without actually having to run the bundles in a real container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the Resolver API in the OSGi spec. Apache Felix has a [resolver implementation](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.resolver) that is also [used by the Equinox framework](http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.osgi/container/src/org/apache/felix/resolver).

Comment: any links? class names? i don't know the name of the Resolver implementation in felix

Comment: also, do you know if i can actually use that code? i would prefer to reuse an already implemented logic instead of just looking at how Felix does it and copying the logic in my own application. In other words, is the Resolver independent enough that i can use it in a different context (my application, not Felix)?

Comment: I updated my answer with some links. The code is self contained. It is used (although in source form) in the Equinox framework implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, it seems the Resolver expects a `org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolveContext` that i don't know how to provide. In the Equinox framework implementation that you provided i don't see any references to the Resolver. Can you include some code on how to use the Resolver? I see in the _main()_ of that jar that ResolveContextImpl gets populated by hand with fake packages, but what i need is something to extract the capabilities and requirements from a real manifest

Comment: You can look at the OSGi spec for a small example. A ResolveContext can be complex to implement since you have to provide the context in which you expect the resolver to resolve. See the [implementation in Equinox](http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.osgi/container/src/org/eclipse/osgi/container/ModuleResolver.java#n405). You can also see the [implementation in bnd](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.resolve/src/biz/aQute/resolve/internal/BndrunResolveContext.java#L59).